# How to return the result of successful calls with Promise.AllSettled as an object

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's more fancy way of returning a result of Promise.allSettled as an object for only successful ones. I have to do it like this, but it does not look for me as a masterpiece. Does anyone have a better approach?

```
        const finalResult = {};

        const objectKeys = [
            'academicPrograms',
            'instructionalMethods',
            'instructionalDeliveryMethods',
            'sites',
            'statusCodes',
            'studentCode',
            'studentResidencyType',
            'studentStatus'
        ];
        const results = await Promise.allSettled([
            this.getAcademicPrograms(),
            this.getInstructionalMethods(),
            this.getInstructionalDeliveryMethods(),
            this.getSites(),
            this.getStatusCodes(),
            this.getStudentCode(),
            this.getStudentResidencyType(),
            this.getStudentStatus()
        ]);

        results.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.status === 'fulfilled') {
                finalResult[objectKeys[index]] = item.value;
            }
        });

        return finalResult;
```

Comment: Don't underestimate yourself its good already.

Comment: We fix broken code, you need to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you have working code that you want to improve upon.

Answer (score 1):

Not better but shorter

```
 const objectKeys = [
  'academicPrograms',
  'instructionalMethods',
  'instructionalDeliveryMethods',
  'sites',
  'statusCodes',
  'studentCode',
  'studentResidencyType',
  'studentStatus'
];

const results = await Promise.allSettled(objectKeys.map(e => this[e]())

const finalResult = results.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
  obj[objectKeys[index]] = item.value
  return obj
}, {})
```